How expensive is throwing an Exception ? (I want a stack trace for non-exception conditions)
One way to get a hold of the current stack trace at any given point is to purposely throw an exception, catch it immediately, and inspect the trace information.  I keep reading about the expense of throwing exceptions, but I'm wondering how expensive.  Of course, I want to be efficient, but it's worth it if it's a reasonable expense.
Any specific thoughts on whether this practice would significantly impact performance, even if it happens semi-frequently, and how to measure it?
p.s. If there is a secret technique for getting stack trace information in non-exception situations, I'd be very interested to learn about it! :)

Throwing an exception to get a stack trace seems like an XY problem. What is the bigger picture here? What does getting a stack trace allow you to do?

@DerekF I'm guessing that this is for a custom logging framework. I've written one myself, and I initially started with throwing exceptions as well. Then, I found a better way.

A long time ago, I asked myself this same question. Back then, it came to about 30-50ms to try-catch an exception. In a trigger of 200 records, it was possible to get upwards of 10,000ms of CPU time just catching one exception per record in a loop.
It was back then that I discovered that you don't actually need to catch (or throw!) the exception. Just construct it yourself.
// Modern implementation, but any exception you can construct should work
AuraHandledException ex = new AuraHandledException('message');
String stackTrace = ex.getStackTraceString();

Revisiting the topic today, it appears that exception handling is much faster than it used to be. A recursive function calling itself 994 times-- the highest I could get it to go in execute anonymous without hitting heap limits-- showed a total time from try to catch of just 2ms. See the two variants I tried at the bottom of this answer.
So, if you really want to generate actual exceptions and throw them, throw away. They cost basically nothing. However, you can make your code leaner by just observing a constructed exception directly. Depending on your framework, this may also make the stack trace a little "cleaner" than it would be without this trick.
// Local try-catch
Long t1;
void recurse(integer i) {
    if(i == 994) {
        t1 = Datetime.now().gettime();
        try {
            Integer z = 0 / 0;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            String stack = e.getStackTraceString();
            Long t2 = Datetime.now().getTime();
            system.debug(t2-t1);
            return;
        }
    }
    recurse(i+1);
}
recurse(0);

// Long try-catch
Long t1;
void recurse(integer i) {
    if(i == 994) {
        t1 = Datetime.now().gettime();
        Integer z = 0 / 0;
    }
    recurse(i+1);
}
try {
    recurse(0);
} catch(Exception e) {
    String stack = e.getStackTraceString();
    Long t2 = Datetime.now().getTime();
    system.debug(t2-t1);
}


Awesome.  Thanks, @sfdxfox!

As someone who specializes in software performance, I don't agree that they are essentially free. If we use this technique frequently, it is pretty expensive. For every 100 executions, that is 200ms of additional execution time, with dubious benefits. If it is rarely used, then you could use this, maybe.

@btlog I'm also an optimization aficionado. This answer focuses solely on CPU usage. Note that the 2ms results included unwinding a 994 deep stack. If you just try-catch in a loop, even 10k iterations only uses 800ms, or 0.08ms per exception. They are very fast, definitely usable in "larger" doses than they used to be. That said, other limits, like heap and overall DML operations still means you have to be careful with how much you use this, or any, logging technique.
